# how to extract multiple polygon in r

Tags: r, r-sf, r-raster

Use this code below to give the mean of each district and this link [CHIRPS tar.gz data](https://edcintl.cr.usgs.gov/downloads/sciweb1/shared/fews/web/global/monthly/chirps/final/downloads/monthly/), for precipitation data, `library(geodata)` for administrative districts.

```
library(sf)
library(raster)
# library(geodata) for gadm shape files
rwanda_shapefile <- st_read("C:/Users/HP/Desktop/IITA/saved_OUTPUT/CHIRPS/PREP/gadm41_RWA_shp/gadm41_RWA_0.shp")

precipitation_data <- raster("C:/Users/HP/Desktop/IITA/saved_OUTPUT/CHIRPS/PREP/chirps-v2.0.2021.08.tif")

district_precipitation <- extract(precipitation_data, rwanda_shapefile)
  
d_mean_prec <- sapply(district_precipitation, mean, na.rm = TRUE)

d_prec$Mean_Prec <- d_mean_prec

print(d_mean_prec)
```

to get the districts with respect their mean precipitation

Comment: Hi Abby. Welcome to stackoverflow. You will find a lot of friends here, if you provide a minimal reproducible example (so we can play around with your problem) and give us some idea on where your code goes wrong/what you tried and why the result is not looking like you expect(ed) it. We appreciate you are a starter ... and we all started small ... but your problem/question does not give us any idea what you hope to get from here.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at `?raster::extract`, its usage is

```
extract(x, y, fun=NULL, na.rm=FALSE, 
  exact=FALSE, weights=FALSE,
  normalizeWeights=TRUE, cellnumbers=FALSE,
  small=TRUE, df=FALSE, layer, nl, 
  factors=FALSE, sp=FALSE, ...)
```

so you can get the mean by precinct in the `extract()` call.

```
library(sf)
library(raster)
library(terra)
library(geodata)

Rwanda_precincts1 = geodata::gadm('RWA', level = 1, path = 'maps')# maps a dir in working directory
precip_wld = terra::rast(R.utils::gunzip('~/Downloads/chirps-v2.0.2021.08.tif.gz', remove = FALSE)) 
raster::extract(precip_wld, Rwanda_precincts1, fun = mean, na.rm = TRUE)
  ID chirps-v2.0.2021.08
1  1            47.29495
2  2            33.24807
3  3            25.63329
4  4            47.92463
5  5            28.60866
```

so `raster::extract` above returns a data.frame with mean precipitation by precinct number. If you want to update values to just mean precip by precinct you could use the following - hearafter using `terra`

```
# clip out the precip from world to just Rwanda
precip_RWA = (crop(precip_wld, Rwanda_precincts1, mask = TRUE)) 
# mask each precinct
RWA_pre1_msk = mask(precip_RWA, Rwanda_precincts1[1])
RWA_pre2_msk = mask(precip_RWA, Rwanda_precincts1[2])
RWA_pre3_msk = mask(precip_RWA, Rwanda_precincts1[3])
RWA_pre4_msk = mask(precip_RWA, Rwanda_precincts1[4])
RWA_pre5_msk = mask(precip_RWA, Rwanda_precincts1[5])
# get extract( values using terra
precip_RWA_df = extract(precip_RWA, Rwanda_precincts1, fun = 'mean', na.rm = TRUE)
# extract from df to vector
precip_vect1 = precip_RWA_df[, 2]
# change RWA_pre1:pre5 cell values to precip_vect1[1:5] values
RWA_pre1_msk[not.na(RWA_pre1_msk)] = precip_vect1[1]
RWA_pre2_msk[not.na(RWA_pre2_msk)] = precip_vect1[2]
RWA_pre3_msk[not.na(RWA_pre3_msk)] = precip_vect1[3]
RWA_pre4_msk[not.na(RWA_pre4_msk)] = precip_vect1[4]
RWA_pre5_msk[not.na(RWA_pre5_msk)] = precip_vect1[5]
# stitch these together with `terra::mosaic(
RWA_precip_mosaic = mosaic(RWA_pre1_msk, RWA_pre2_msk, RWA_pre3_msk, RWA_pre4_msk, RWA_pre5_msk, fun = 'min')
plot(RWA_precip_mosaic)
```

There are likely other, better ways to do this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Example data

```
library(terra)
library(geodata)
rwanda1 <- geodata::gadm("Rwanda", level=1, path=".")
precip <- rast(floor(ext(rwanda1)), nlyr=10, res=.1)
precip <- init(precip, runif)
```

Get the values

```
dist_precip <- extract(precip, rwanda1, fun=mean, na.rm=TRUE)
```

Get the values as a SpatVector

```
dpv <- extract(precip, rwanda1, fun=mean, bind=TRUE, na.rm=TRUE)
```

Get the values as a SpatRaster

```
dpr <- zonal(precip, rwanda1, as.raster=TRUE, na.rm=TRUE)
```

If you also wanted to aggregate the raster layers then first do

```
precip <- sum(precip, na.rm=TRUE)
```